# Date Manipulation in Informix DB

Tags: sql, date, informix

based on other forum entries, I believe that I need to utilise the below code to convert a date in Informix to a month:

```
select
MONTH(DATE_FIELD) as "Month Conversion"
from TABLE
```

Unfortunately when I run it, I get this error

> Error: ERROR  Mixed numeric and alpha operands in expression -
>   job_cost_master.jcm_start_date SQLState:  42000 ErrorCode: -1

Comment: "*based on other forum entries, I believe*" - why don't you simply look this up in the manual?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a column ALIAS with spaces and/or in quotes.
This should work:

select
MONTH(DATE_FIELD) as month_conversion
from TABLE

Regards

Comment: Oh...you're mostly right.  If you set DELIMIDENT=1 in the environment (the value on the RHS doesn't matter), you can use a delimited identifier in double quotes containing spaces.  Otherwise, you can't.